Optimize a PostGIS Query with Dynamic Parameters and Partitioned Tables
I'm building a spatial query as part of a client-side application where the user can input dynamic parameters (e.g., bounding boxes, distances). The query calculates intersections between lines (generated from grid cells) and polygons (building footprints).Here's how I partitioned the building_footprints table by utm zone:
ALTER TABLE building_footprints ADD COLUMN utm_zone INTEGER;

UPDATE building_footprints
SET utm_zone = 32600 + FLOOR((ST_X(ST_Centroid(geom)) + 180) / 6) + 1;

CREATE TABLE building_footprints_partitioned (
    LIKE building_footprints INCLUDING ALL
) PARTITION BY LIST (utm_zone);

CREATE TABLE building_footprints_zone_32612 PARTITION OF building_footprints_partitioned FOR VALUES IN (32612);
CREATE TABLE building_footprints_zone_32613 PARTITION OF building_footprints_partitioned FOR VALUES IN (32613);
CREATE TABLE building_footprints_zone_32614 PARTITION OF building_footprints_partitioned FOR VALUES IN (32614);
CREATE TABLE building_footprints_zone_32615 PARTITION OF building_footprints_partitioned FOR VALUES IN (32615);

INSERT INTO building_footprints_partitioned SELECT * FROM building_footprints;

CREATE INDEX ON building_footprints_zone_32612 USING GIST (geom);
CREATE INDEX ON building_footprints_zone_32613 USING GIST (geom);
CREATE INDEX ON building_footprints_zone_32614 USING GIST (geom);
CREATE INDEX ON building_footprints_zone_32615 USING GIST (geom);

And here's the query I'm using with some default values (bounding box and distance of line) for testing purposes:
WITH bbox AS (
SELECT ST_MakeEnvelope(-110.7671182701987, 43.487474778687584,-110.76170649280083,43.49209387134351, 4326) AS geom
),
dynamic_utm AS (
SELECT 
geom,
(32600 + FLOOR((ST_X(ST_Centroid(geom)) + 180) / 6) + 1)::integer AS utm_srid
FROM bbox
),
transformed_bbox AS (
SELECT ST_Transform(geom, utm_srid) AS transformed_geom, utm_srid
FROM dynamic_utm
),
filtered_buildings AS (
SELECT ST_Simplify(b.geom, 10) AS simplified_geom, b.*
FROM building_footprints_partitioned b
JOIN dynamic_utm ON b.utm_zone = dynamic_utm.utm_srid
JOIN transformed_bbox ON transformed_bbox.utm_srid = dynamic_utm.utm_srid
WHERE b.geom && ST_Expand(transformed_bbox.transformed_geom, 500)
AND ST_DWithin(b.geom, transformed_bbox.transformed_geom, 500)
),

grid AS (
SELECT (ST_SquareGrid(30, transformed_bbox.transformed_geom)).geom AS grid_cell
FROM transformed_bbox
),
lines AS (
SELECT 
ST_Centroid(g.grid_cell) AS start_point,
ST_MakeLine(ST_Centroid(g.grid_cell), ST_Project(ST_Centroid(g.grid_cell), 500, radians(angle))) AS line,
angle,
g.grid_cell
FROM grid g,
generate_series(0, 360, 1) AS angle
),
intersections AS (
SELECT 
l.line, 
l.angle,
l.start_point,
l.grid_cell,
b.geom AS polygon,
CASE 
WHEN ST_Intersects(l.line, b.geom) THEN ST_Intersection(l.line, b.geom)
ELSE NULL
END AS intersection,
CASE 
WHEN ST_Intersects(l.line, b.geom) THEN ST_Distance(ST_StartPoint(l.line), ST_Intersection(l.line, b.geom))
ELSE 500
END AS distance
FROM lines l
LEFT JOIN filtered_buildings b 
ON b.geom && l.line AND ST_Intersects(b.geom, l.line)  -- Modified line
),
angle_pairs AS (
SELECT 
i1.start_point,
i1.grid_cell,
i1.angle AS angle_1,
i1.distance AS distance_1,
i2.angle AS angle_2,
i2.distance AS distance_2,
i1.distance + i2.distance AS total_distance
FROM intersections i1
JOIN intersections i2
ON i1.start_point = i2.start_point
AND (i1.angle + 180) % 360 = i2.angle
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (angle_pairs.grid_cell)
ST_AsText(ST_Transform(angle_pairs.grid_cell, 4326)) AS grid_cell_polygon, 
angle_1,
distance_1,
angle_2,
distance_2,
total_distance
FROM angle_pairs
ORDER BY angle_pairs.grid_cell, angle_pairs.total_distance;

The query runs in ~116 seconds, with the majority of the time spent in the intersections CTE.Here are my Explain Analyze results for the above query:
 "Unique  (cost=40439543.98..40442802.01 rows=200 width=96) (actual time=116060.127..116227.848 rows=270 loops=1)"
"  CTE dynamic_utm"
"    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  CTE transformed_bbox"
"    ->  CTE Scan on dynamic_utm  (cost=0.00..12.52 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.021..0.023 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  CTE intersections"
"    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.53..31702835.12 rows=361000 width=281) (actual time=1.554..112445.098 rows=181703 loops=1)"
"          Join Filter: ((b.geom && st_makeline(st_centroid((((st_squaregrid('30'::double precision, transformed_bbox_1.transformed_geom))).geom)), st_project(st_centroid((((st_squaregrid('30'::double precision, transformed_bbox_1.transformed_geom))).geom)), '500'::double precision, radians((angle.angle)::double precision)))) AND st_intersects(b.geom, st_makeline(st_centroid((((st_squaregrid('30'::double precision, transformed_bbox_1.transformed_geom))).geom)), st_project(st_centroid((((st_squaregrid('30'::double precision, transformed_bbox_1.transformed_geom))).geom)), '500'::double precision, radians((angle.angle)::double precision)))))"
"          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 16652048"
"          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..5169.26 rows=361000 width=36) (actual time=0.050..57.700 rows=97470 loops=1)"
"                ->  Function Scan on generate_series angle  (cost=0.00..3.61 rows=361 width=4) (actual time=0.020..0.621 rows=361 loops=1)"
"                ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..655.65 rows=1000 width=32) (actual time=0.000..0.046 rows=270 loops=361)"
"                      ->  Result  (cost=0.00..640.65 rows=1000 width=32) (actual time=0.028..0.391 rows=270 loops=1)"
"                            ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..5.65 rows=1000 width=32) (actual time=0.027..0.331 rows=270 loops=1)"
"                                  ->  CTE Scan on transformed_bbox transformed_bbox_1  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.021..0.022 rows=1 loops=1)"
"          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.53..60.86 rows=1 width=141) (actual time=0.000..0.011 rows=172 loops=97470)"
"                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.53..60.86 rows=1 width=141) (actual time=0.108..0.816 rows=172 loops=1)"
"                      Join Filter: (b.utm_zone = dynamic_utm_1.utm_srid)"
"                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.53..60.82 rows=1 width=149) (actual time=0.107..0.754 rows=172 loops=1)"
"                            ->  CTE Scan on transformed_bbox  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                            ->  Append  (cost=0.53..60.76 rows=4 width=145) (actual time=0.106..0.721 rows=172 loops=1)"
"                                  ->  Index Scan using idx_geom_32612 on building_footprints_zone_32612 b_1  (cost=0.53..15.25 rows=1 width=146) (actual time=0.100..0.701 rows=172 loops=1)"
"                                        Index Cond: ((geom && st_expand(transformed_bbox.transformed_geom, '500'::double precision)) AND (geom && st_expand(transformed_bbox.transformed_geom, '500'::double precision)))"
"                                        Filter: ((transformed_bbox.utm_srid = utm_zone) AND st_dwithin(geom, transformed_bbox.transformed_geom, '500'::double precision))"
"                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 4"
"                                  ->  Index Scan using building_footprints_zone_32613_geom_idx2 on building_footprints_zone_32613 b_2  (cost=0.53..15.26 rows=1 width=146) (never executed)"
"                                        Index Cond: ((geom && st_expand(transformed_bbox.transformed_geom, '500'::double precision)) AND (geom && st_expand(transformed_bbox.transformed_geom, '500'::double precision)))"
"                                        Filter: ((transformed_bbox.utm_srid = utm_zone) AND st_dwithin(geom, transformed_bbox.transformed_geom, '500'::double precision))"
"                                  ->  Index Scan using building_footprints_zone_32614_geom_idx2 on building_footprints_zone_32614 b_3  (cost=0.40..15.12 rows=1 width=36) (never executed)"
"                                        Index Cond: ((geom && st_expand(transformed_bbox.transformed_geom, '500'::double precision)) AND (geom && st_expand(transformed_bbox.transformed_geom, '500'::double precision)))"
"                                        Filter: ((transformed_bbox.utm_srid = utm_zone) AND st_dwithin(geom, transformed_bbox.transformed_geom, '500'::double precision))"
"                                  ->  Index Scan using building_footprints_zone_32615_geom_idx2 on building_footprints_zone_32615 b_4  (cost=0.40..15.12 rows=1 width=36) (never executed)"
"                                        Index Cond: ((geom && st_expand(transformed_bbox.transformed_geom, '500'::double precision)) AND (geom && st_expand(transformed_bbox.transformed_geom, '500'::double precision)))"
"                                        Filter: ((transformed_bbox.utm_srid = utm_zone) AND st_dwithin(geom, transformed_bbox.transformed_geom, '500'::double precision))"
"                      ->  CTE Scan on dynamic_utm dynamic_utm_1  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=172)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=8736696.33..8738325.35 rows=651605 width=96) (actual time=116060.125..116162.394 rows=300654 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: i1.grid_cell, ((i1.distance + i2.distance))"
"        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 109088kB"
"        ->  Merge Join  (cost=81086.52..8654204.77 rows=651605 width=96) (actual time=113813.500..115081.902 rows=300654 loops=1)"
"              Merge Cond: ((i1.start_point = i2.start_point) AND ((((i1.angle + 180) % 360)) = i2.angle))"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=40543.26..41445.76 rows=361000 width=76) (actual time=113489.752..113514.209 rows=181703 loops=1)"
"                    Sort Key: i1.start_point, (((i1.angle + 180) % 360))"
"                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 44472kB"
"                    ->  CTE Scan on intersections i1  (cost=0.00..7220.00 rows=361000 width=76) (actual time=1.558..112884.849 rows=181703 loops=1)"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=40543.26..41445.76 rows=361000 width=44) (actual time=322.990..352.735 rows=300951 loops=1)"
"                    Sort Key: i2.start_point, i2.angle"
"                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 21760kB"
"                    ->  CTE Scan on intersections i2  (cost=0.00..7220.00 rows=361000 width=44) (actual time=0.095..35.145 rows=181703 loops=1)"
"Planning Time: 0.783 ms"
"Execution Time: 116245.805 ms"

The query needs to handle dynamic bounding boxes and distances, so some of the logic must remain adaptable. How can I improve the performance of spatial joins in this query, particularly the intersections CTE?

Pgpartman can handle your partitions dynamically. You can build one index on the partitioned table and individual indexes on each partition will be created automatically. You can use projected geometries in UTM ref systems, then partition by st_srid() without handling it all explicitly. I can't test or even read into it now, but you typically don't need full flexibility on the grid generator and bboxes - look into precomputing them both down to some granularity, save them to indexed and clustered tables, then use the user params to switch between them rather than create them on the fly.

You can try to materialize the CTEs, it might help to cut time in half. (grid AS MATERIALIZED ( ... ), lines AS MATERIALIZED (...)).

But it is not the join that is taking a long time, it is building the lines. From your sample query, you are building 361 lines for each grid cell, and there are 270 grid cells so 97 470 lines to be created. It takes time and memory. Instead, you can create 1 set of lines centred over 0;0, and then offset them toward each grid centroid.

And if this fails to drastically improve the speed, you can also compute the lines, put them in a temporary table with a spatial index, and use this temp table to join the building. In your sample query, there are only 172 filtered buildings, and it would be faster to do a seq scan on them and use a spatial index over the lines.

Thanks @JGH. Your first two suggestions definitely improved my query time.
